# SQL query fetching data and insert to db

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, create-table

Table `employeeAccount`:

```
CREATE TABLE employeeAccount
( 
    employAccID NUMBER(2),
    emplyUsername VARCHAR(20),
    emplyFirstName VARCHAR(20),
    emplyLastName VARCHAR(20),
)

INSERT INTO employeeAccount(employAccID ,emplyUsername ) VALUES (1,'TestAccount1')
INSERT INTO employeeAccount(employAccID ,emplyUsername ) VALUES (2,'TestAccount2')
```

Table `JobRole`:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobrole
( 
    jobNo NUMBER(2),
    jobName VARCHAR(20),
)

INSERT INTO Jobrole(jobNo ,jobName) VALUES (001,'Admin')
INSERT INTO Jobrole(jobNo ,jobName) VALUES (002,'CEO')
```

And here is my `employeeJob` code:

```
CREATE TABLE employeeJob
(
  empid NUMBER(2),
  empjob NUMBER(2),
  CONSTRAINT pk_employeeJob PRIMARY KEY(empid,empjob),
  CONSTRAINT fk_empassignjob1 FOREIGN KEY(empid) REFERENCES employeeAccount(employAccID),
 CONSTRAINT fk_empassignjob2 FOREIGN KEY(empjob) REFERENCES Jobrole(jobNo)
)
```

Below is the insertion query:

```
INSERT INTO employeeJob(empid,empjob)
VALUES (1,'001')
```

Any idea how do I make it automatic take all the data like `emplyFirstName`, `emplyLastName` from `employeeAccount` table & insert to `employeeJob`. How should I do that to make it auto insert other data that existing from `employeeAccount` duplicate to `employeeJob` table?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Create a procedure that receives all your data. Inside the procedure add the new job info if it doesn't exist, the new account if it doesn't exist and the new relationship between the job and the person if it doesn't exist. Then you just need to call the procedure with every account data and done!

Comment: i using myORA , sorry for not inserting the information to this post

Comment: Copying data as you ask is not how you should be manipulating data in a RDBMS.  After your insert, to see the job with employee details is a query operation that joins these tables to get the information.  You don’t want to have a second copy of the data.  Imagine what happens if you have to follow up with an update of the name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

You can populate `table2` automatically from `table1`. If you want all the records, ignore the `WHERE` condition. However, if you want to automatically populate only certain records from `table1` to `table2` write the `condition` in `WHERE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger on the `employeejob` table on insert like

```
Create trigger trgGetOtherDetails
On employeejob AFTER INSERT -- the AFTER key word is Necessary
AS
BEGIN
Declare @emplyFirstname   varchar(30), 
@emplyLastname   varchar(30),
@empId      varchar(5)

select @empId = empId from inserted

Select @emplyFirstname = emplyFirstname, @emplyLastname = emplyLastname from employeeAccount where employAccID = @empId

Update employeejob 
Set emplyFirstname = @emplyFirstname, 
emplyLastname = @emplyLastname 
Where empId = @empId

END
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply . it look great . but i got an error "ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword" . and other question is that "Where empId = inserted.empId" , can i change the inserted to 1 ? as I am doing fixed sql , not dynamic(insert from form)

Comment: @thenewsboy for the error you probably missed the "AFTER" key word in the query. I've Edited my code once again. this should work for you. And the "inserted" is a temporary table managed by SQL Server automatically. It stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT and UPDATE statements. So you can easily get any info of the affected row. Sorry for the late reply